# Opposite of style.display='none' to reshow canvas

Tags: javascript

In Javascript I understand you can hide a canvas (c1 say) using `c1.style.display='none'`. What's the opposite word please to make a canvas visible again?

Comment: `c1.style.display = 'block'`

Comment: Thanks, I saw the word block in some code samples but I thought it meant block it, as in still don't show..
 It seems a strange word to use to imply visible!

Comment: [display property at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, use:

```javascript
c1.style.display = 'contents'
```